# How to return an array of children from firebase in React-Native

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase data base contains JSON objects, each with the same parameters as seen below. [Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5mGl.png)

I want to get an array that has each objects country. So if I have 4,000 objects I want to get an array of 4,000 strings all containing a country.

Right now I can get the console to log all the 4,000 objects into an array using the code below.

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.fetchData();
}
fetchData = async () => {
    var data1 = [];
    var fireBaseResponse = firebase.database().ref();
    fireBaseResponse.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(item => {
            var temp = item.val();
            data1.push(temp);
            return false;
   });
   console.log(data1);
   });
}
```

But when I try doing

```
 var fireBaseResponse = firebase.database().ref().child('country');
```

I get an array of nothing.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I believe you have to use `snapshot.val()` to access the returned object

Comment: I do for each item and I do get an array of 4,000 objects. The thing is the array has all the item info and not just country.

Comment: Then you should extract `item.val().country` into a new object before pushing it into `data1`. I hope this helps!

Comment: Your right. I cannot believe I did not see that. Thanks so much

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can create a new temp object containing just country before pushing it into your array.

```
snapshot.forEach(item => {
    var temp = { country: item.val().country };
    data1.push(temp);
    return false;
});
```